# Why is this combination grammatically correct? "Sports the world over..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *Sports the world over are looking to other industries for inspiration, not least the technology and engineering sectors* ([Source: BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-36854284)).

Should it be **"the world over sports are..."**? If so, please tell me the difference.

Comment: Sure, it is on the BBC. http://www.bbc.com/news/business-36854284

Comment: Why do you want to write it differently?

Answer (score 4):

"The world over" is an idiom which functions as an adjectival following its head, meaning "everywhere". **Edit:** There is a little variation in the words, but not much. I've found:

- the world over
- the whole world over
- all the world over

  and possibly with *around* instead of *over*, (but it's hard to be sure because most cases of *the world around* are followed by *you* or *us* or *me*, which is a different constructio).

It can be used as an adverbial as well:

> Search the world over, and you'll not find anybody like him.

Comment: The Google provides copious [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+whole+world+over%22#q=%22the+whole+world+over%22&tbs=li:1) of _the **whole** world over_ used in the same sense.

Comment: @P.E.Dant As in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVDEPWxVbwM) classic.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: True. Edited accordingly.